# JNI: How can i check if jobject is a null object in native c code

Tags: object, null, java-native-interface

JNI: How can i check if jobject is a null object in native c code

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the objects in Java and C code actually use the same memory locations (the object passed to the native code is the same memory reference in both worlds), a simple

```
if (someJObject == NULL) {}
```

in the C code should be just fine I guess. I haven't tested it though :-)

Comment: I have tested this. It works.  A 'null' Java object (as a jobject) == NULL in C++.

Comment: Silly Oracle.  That address is no longer valid.  For now, this Sun IP address is working for me: http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jni/html/design.html

Comment: While this works most times, I encountered situations where someJObject was != NULL, but still represented the Java-null. A safer test is
(*env)->IsSameObject(env, someJObject, NULL)
which always worked, so I would recommend that one.

Answer (score 28):

Stewori's comment deserves to be an answer, so here it is:

```
(*env)->IsSameObject(env, someJObject, NULL)
```

I think that this test succeeds where value comparison fails when the reference type is JNIWeakGlobalRefType, vs a local or a global ref.

Comment: should it be `(*env)->NewLocalRef(env, someJObject) == NULL` instead? The weak reference may freed at any time, so the check is useless without some kind of lock

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer and the other answers are all correct.
But to be more clear, you can always check

```
if (someJObject == NULL) {}
```

for both local and global references.

As for a weak global reference, you should use

```
(*env)->IsSameObject(env, someJObject, NULL)
```

because the original object on Java side could be garbage collected already while the **someJObject** on C side still has the old reference value.
So it's safe to say the latter always will work for both cases.

But there's another thing to note here. You shouldn't call any JNI functions based on the result value of **IsSameObject()**, if it's a weak global reference.
This is because the object can be garbage collected anytime, even just after getting TRUE from **IsSameObject()**.
You can get what I mean from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.70.doc/diag/understanding/jni_refs.html).

So, personally I think you may choose whatever you want unless you're dealing with some special cases with weak global references. For simple cases, the former is more easy to read and even cheaper than calling a JNI function.